# Is it feasible to bundle dynamic libraries with dependencies in a Tcl Starkit/Starpack?

Tags: shared-libraries, tcl

I've written a Tcl script that uses the TclMagick extension together with GraphicsMagick.

For GraphicsMagick, I've both the Windows DLLs and the Linux SO files. I want to be able to make two Starkit/Starpack applications bundled with those libraries: one for Windows (with the DLLs) and one for Linux (with the SO files).

Is this reasonable? Can it be done?

**EDIT**

I cannot seem to use DLLs with dependencies under Windows. In my case, I want to use the TclMagick extension, but it needs the GraphicsMagick's DLLs and the starkit cannot find those. What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but you might need some extra windows trickery to get things to work properly.

Windows has quite a few options to load dependent libraries, this page explains the basics:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There are is one part that can help you:

> If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system checks only for redirection and a manifest before resolving to the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL.

So, to get the dependencies right, you could get the dependent libraries loaded into memory first (sadly you cannot use `load` for this, but could use something from twapi, e.g. `twapi::load_libary` (see http://wiki.tcl.tk/9886) to get the library loaded from some temporary location).

Sadly most OS's do not provide an easy or portable way to load a dynamic library directly from memory, so you need to copy the dependent libs to a temporary location first (you can do it with appropriate hacks or by using something like an installable filesystem on windows/FUSE on Linux).

In most cases the easiest route is to just link all dependencies statically into the extension instead.

Comment: The solution in my case was static linking. Apparently, copying DLLs to the temp folder and loading them is considered "malware behavior" for most antivirus and this can cause problems to the users.

Comment: Yes. Most systems have their own 'bundling' system by now, so those are expected to be used (e.g. Side-by-Side Assemblies/Isolated Applications using manifests on windows, or App Bundles on OS X). Doesn't help much with cross platform things. And most AV systems just flag anything they don't know as dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the `lib/tclmagick` subdirectory of `$starkit::topdir`, you'll place the dynamic library and an appropriate `pkgIndex.tcl` file that `load`s the library. Use a Makefile or some other build script to use the correct dynamic library file, and generate the pkgIndex, depending the target platform.

The directory hierarchy:

```
appname.vfs/
    main.tcl
    lib/
        app-appname/
            appname.tcl
            pkgIndex.tcl
        tclmagick/
            pkgIndex.tcl
            tclMagick.so
```

`package require tclmagick` will work as you expect, for some capitalization of "tclmagick"